# JQuery fails to react on a change when selecting blank option

Tags: jquery

When selecting blank option (positioned at 0th location) jquery fails to launch change trigger.

---

**Update: 
My bad, it actually works just fine. I was trying to execute code in a wrong place. Oops.
As always jQuery rocks!!!**

---

Here what I have that work perfectly fine when selecting non-blank options:

```
<select id="asdf">  
    <option value=""></option>  
    <option value="1">1</option>  
    <option value="2">2</option>  
</select>
```

```
    $("#asdf").change(function() {  
    var value = $(f).val();  
    $.post("_asdf.php", {value:value}, function(data) {  
        if(parseInt(data) == 0) {  
            alert('bad');  
        }  
        else {  
            alert('good');  
        }  
    });  
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: learn to use the 'vote' and 'accept answer' buttons, and give a short code sample

Comment: please do that.. (like @Matt said) if you have any answers in your old questions that actually helped you to resolve the problems.. press on a little checkmark that is under the vote counter of the answer ;)

Comment: sorry about not providing code... i updated my post with it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code for a test

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<span></span>
```

Javascript:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $("span").text($(this).val());
});
```

It works fine for me, even if I run it with really old 1.2 version. You can try it in any online javascript tool, like http://jsfiddle.net/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a different cause. In my case, I was doing a post that reloaded the drop down and removed the .change() event. Putting the $('select').change(fooFunction) in the $.post solved the problem.